# How create a navbar with two colors using bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, navbar

How I can create a nav-bar with two colors using less and bootstrap 3 like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/208/fity.png/

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default bootstrap HTML code to create the navbar.
If you don't want their styles, you can remove the 'navbar-default' class.

Then you just want to float the `<ul class="nav">` inside the `<nav>` to the right, give it a background-color and add a triangle onto the front of it.

To make the triangle, I'd create a `:before` pseudo-element for the `<ul class="nav">` and use [CSS borders](http://www.css3shapes.com/) to create the triangle.  Then negatively margin that :before element to bring it in front of the nav, and you're away.

I've made a fiddle with the HTML and the CSS.

Should certainly get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/5JzdU/